# Django model not being saved after calling save()?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm overriding a ModelForm's save method. I'm parsing an Excel file and, if there are some values, I update a quantity in the form's instance related objects. It works the first time, when the instance has no related objects. But the second time, when I'm updating the values, nothing happens. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the `commit` parameter.

EDIT - Relevant code:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    """
    Overrides the save method in order to add the product inventory items listed in
    the uploaded Excel file, if one was uploaded.
    """
    inventory = super(AddOrChangeProductsInventoryForm, self).save(commit)

    self._update_inventory_items_quantities()

    if not commit:
        inventory.save()
        self.save_m2m()

    return inventory

def _update_inventory_items_quantities(self):
    inventory = self.instance

    if len(self.excel_data_dict) == 0:
        return inventory

    non_existing_products = []

    for i, product_sku in enumerate(self.excel_data_dict['SKU']):
        quantity = self.excel_data_dict['Cantidad'][i]
        new_item = inventory.productinventoryitem_set.filter(product__sku=product_sku).first()

        if new_item is None:
            product = Product.objects.filter(sku=product_sku).first()

            if product is None:
                # TODO: Raise warning in view
                non_existing_products.append(product_sku)
                continue

            new_item = ProductInventoryItem()
            new_item.product = product
            new_item.inventory = inventory

        new_item.quantity += quantity
        # TODO: Check why after first update it's not being updated
```

Comment: `inventory = super(AddOrChangeProductsInventoryForm, self).save(commit)` shouldn't it be `.save(commit=commit)`?

Comment: Since it's the only parameter, isn't it implied by its posición?

Answer (score 0):

If your model has any many-to-many relations, then you need to be sure and use `self.save_m2m()` in combination with the save method. Here's a quick example:

```
# save method of your forms.ModelForm class.
def save(self):
    obj = super(MyModelForm, self).save(commit=False)
    obj.save()
    self.save_m2m()
    return obj
```

Comment: I tried what you posted to no avail. Maybe I'm updating the related objects wrong?

Comment: @Pepedou I would try removing the `commit=True` argument from your save method and instead specify `commit=False` as the argument on the line where you're calling `super`. Also remove the statement, `if not commit` and just let that code get executed every time. If those changes don't work, then it must be something in your `_update_inventory` method.

Comment: @Pepedou also it looks like you need to do a `new_item.save()` after you assign it a product and inventory.

Comment: I've tried all those things you mention and it still isn't working. The funny thing is that if I override the `_save_m2m` method and do something like `for obj in self.instance.productinventoryitem_set.all():
    obj.quantity += 2 obj.save()` the quantities updated successfully...

Answer (score 0):

You are saving form when commit is False.
Replace (line 10):

```
if not commit:
```

with:

```
if commit:
```

**UPDATE:**

`new_item` is new copy of `inventory.productinventoryitem_set.filter(product__sku=product_sku).first()`

or

```
ProductInventoryItem()
```

It is local variable and it is not updating `inventory`. All these changes will destroy after executing the function. You need to store changes in `inventory`.

When you are overriding `_save_m2m` in:

```
for obj in self.instance.productinventoryitem_set.all(): 
    obj.quantity += 2 
    obj.save()
```

Then you are saving changes before destroying.

You can do something like this:

```
def save(self, commit=True):

    inventory = super(AddOrChangeProductsInventoryForm, self).save(commit)

    self._update_inventory_items_quantities(inventory, commit)

    return inventory

def _update_inventory_items_quantities(self, inventory, commit):

    if len(self.excel_data_dict) == 0:
        return inventory

    non_existing_products = []

    for i, product_sku in enumerate(self.excel_data_dict['SKU']):
        quantity = self.excel_data_dict['Cantidad'][i]
        new_item = inventory.productinventoryitem_set.filter(product__sku=product_sku).first()

        if new_item is None:
            product = Product.objects.filter(sku=product_sku).first()

            if product is None:
                # TODO: Raise warning in view
                non_existing_products.append(product_sku)
                continue

            new_item = ProductInventoryItem()
            new_item.product = product
            new_item.inventory = inventory

        new_item.quantity += quantity
        if commit:
            new_item.save()
```

Comment: I've removed that condition entirely and still there's no change.